# Blank space on the right of the site and unwanted X-scrolling

Tags: css, navbar, viewport

I have a problem with an unwanted blank space on the right of of my site and X-scrolling. It seems to me that the navbar causes the problem, as it stretches beyond the container. Via the Google Developer mode I can switch off the clear:both parameter of the navbar and the space will disappear, but the rest of the CSSS will be broken.

The viewport width is set to device width and initial scale is set to 1. Can anyone help me out and give a solution?

The site address is poiskdetei.ru or en.poiskdetei.ru (English version)

Tnank you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **SO**. I am not sure why that area is there, but I do know one way you could fix it.

You could simply add `overflow-x: hidden` to the area that is going over. Then it will not be visible to users, and the scrollbar will not be there anymore.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Well, I have tried to do it, but it it did not fix the problem. Perhaps I was adding it wrong, I  added it to the style of the div element that was going over.

Comment: The Manoj's solution fixed the problem but your suggestion is also very reasonable. Thank you both for your quickly solving the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The unwanted x-scrolling is caused by a `row` which is unwrapped inside a container and hence the default margin of -15px makes it to stretch the body.

**Unwrapped row**

[image: Error]

**Output after wrapping**

[image]

Comment: Similar problem, however, remains on the mobile version where it is much more irritating ( on Iphone 5s, Safari at least). Perhaps you also know the solution for this issue?

Comment: I guess it is cache issue but I can't reproduce that issue on smaller screen size here.

Comment: Cleared the cache with no results. Will try on Android devices and different screen sizes, firstly. Thank you once more for your help!

Comment: Ok, so finally your advice combined with  applying "overflow-x:hidden" to body and html ( thanx to Michael Jones) is the solution. Everything works like charm, no horizontal scrollbars on mobiles anymore.